how to use string to be key of array in php
I have array that need to call.
$array['first_key']['second_key'] = 'value';
$keys = "['first_key']['second_key']";
I want to call it $array.$key that like $array['first_key']['second_key'].
Any one can help?

In Laravel, the easiest way to access nested dynamic array keys is by using the dot notation, ie first_key.second_key. Laravel's Illuminate\Support\Arr helper contains a method Arr::get that allows accessing nested array keys by using the dot notation. You can similarly also use Arr::set to set nested values using dot notation For example
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$key = 'first_key.second_key';

$array['first_key']['second_key'] = 'value';
// or
Arr::set($array, $key, 'value');


$value = Arr::get($array, $key);

